# Is conversion from basic system types to string reversible?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

When storing an object in a string, can I ensure that casting it back will perform successfully does it depend on something else?

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.UtcNow;
string pattern = dt.ToString();
DateTime retDt = DateTime.Parse(pattern);
```

This question is asking about the following object types:

- TimeSpan
- DateTime
- int
- long
- float
- double

I have tried reading several forums and saw no contradicting example. I also haven't
got any exceptions from my code yet, but I am sure I haven't tried all possible inputs/scenarios.

Comment: What concrete problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @SpencerRuport - I am limited to storing those object types to two string variables - pattern and format. I need the ability to convert them  back.

Comment: @Yosi it depends on the **structure** (how much info it contains?), the overridden `ToString()` and the parser `Parse`. It's hard to say for `DateTime` and `TimeSpan`, however we just need to look into their structures in depth to get the answer.

Comment: Yosi if all you need to do is store all these types as a string I think a more reliable solution would be to Binary Serialize them and convert them to Base64 encoding so you can store them as strings. Is there any reason that wouldn't work?

Comment: @SpencerRuport - won't this make the code much less readable? i will take this as an option only if this isn't safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `ToString` you can specify a format (see [this topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy.aspx) for more information) for numbers and time.

The format you would want to use in many these cases is the **round-trip** format ("R" for  Single, Double, and BigInteger types, "O" for DateTime.) This format ensures all the information passes to the string, and can be parsed back to the exact same data.

Passing an `IFormatProvider` to `ToString` is also essential to avoid problems with locales (for example, different locales can use different characters for the decimal separator.) Using the static `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` solves this problem.

Lastly, if you're trying to persist data and then retrieve it, you may want to consider using a **serializer**, which takes **entire classes** and writes them to various formats. .NET has several serializers, two of the most prominent ones being the `BinaryFormatter` (binary) and the `DataContractSerializer` (XML).

Answer (score 1):

Parse and ToString being able to convert to and from the type of your choice depends on their implementation.  For the default the conversion will work without any change.

Take care with DateTime though as you might want to specify to output the timezone information with ToString so that your parse will create the new DateTime with the correct time zone information.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be aware that culture specific settings come into play when using the default `ToString` implementation for these types.

If you always deserialize on the same machine that did the serialization, it should not be an issue (unless the user can change their culture settings between serialization and deserialization).

If you intend to deserialize on a different machine you should try to use a culture invariant representation. All of these types have overloads of `ToString` that take a format specifier. Unfortunately, the culture invariant specifiers are all slightly different. For the numeric types it is "r" (the "round-trip" format). For `DateTime`, it is "o". For `TimeSpan` it is "c". Typically the `Parse` methods accept current culture format or invariant format. Watch out for `ParseExact` methods.